# Azure Service Bus - Two Way Communication Performance Challenge

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, azure-web-roles, servicebus, azureservicebus

I need to establish a two-way communication between a Publisher and a Subscriber. This is to facilitate a front-end MVC3 application defining a Subscription with a Correlation Filter, and then placing a message onto a Topic. Finally, the MVC3 controller calls BeginReceive() on the SubscriptionClient, and awaits the response.

The issue seems to be the creation and deletion of these Subscription objects. The overhead is enormous, and it slows the application to a crawl. This is not to mention the various limitations to work around, such as no more than 2000 Subscriptions on a Topic.

What is the best practice for establishing this kind of two-way communication between a Publisher and Subscriber? We want the MVC3 app to publish a message and then wait for a response to that exact message (via the CorrelationId property and a CorrelationFilter). We already cache the NamespaceManager and MessagingFactory, as those are also prohibitively expensive, resource-wise, and also because we were advised that Service Bus uses an explicit provisioning model, where we are expected to pre-create most of these things during role startup.

So, this leaves us with the challenge of correlating request to response, and having this tremendous overhead of the creation and deletion of Subscriptions. What better practice exists? Should we keep a cache of SubscriptionClients, and swap the Filter each time? What does everyone else do? I need to have a request throughput on the order of 5 to 10 thousand MVC3 requests per second through the Web Role cluster. We are already using AsyncController and employing the asynchronous BeginReceive() on SubscriptionClient. It appears to be the creation and deletion of the Subscriptions by the thousands that is choking the system at this point.

**UPDATE1:**
Based on the great advice provided here, we have updated this solution to keep a cache of SubscriptionClient objects on each web role instance. Additionally, we have migrated to a MessageSession oriented approach.

However, this is still not scaling. It seems that AcceptMessageSession() is a very expensive operation. Should MessageSession objects also be cached and re-used? Does each open MessageSession object consume a connection to the Service Bus? If so, is this counted against the Subscription's concurrent connection quota?

Many thanks. I think we are getting there. Most of the example code on the web shows: Create Topic(), then CreateSubscription(), then CreateSubscriptionClient(), then BeginReceive() on the client, then teardown of all of the objects. All I can say is if you did this in real life, your server would be crushed, and you would max out on connections in no time.

We need to put thousands of requests per second through this thing, and it is very apparent that these objects must be cached and reused heavily. So, is MessageSession yet another item to cache? I will have fun caching that, because we will have to implement a reference counting mechanism, where only one reference to the MessageSession can be given out at a time, since this is for http request-specific request/response, and we cannot have other subscribers using the MessageSession objects concurrently.

**UPDATE2:**
OK, it is not feasible to cache MessageSession for re-use, because they only live as long as the LockDuration on the Subscription. This is a bummer, because the maximum LockDuration is 5 minutes. These appear to be for pub/sub of short duration, not for long-running distributed processes. It looks like we need to back to polling Azure Tables.

**SUMMARY/COMMENTARY**
We tried to build on Service Bus because of the scale potential and its durability and delivery semantics. However, it seems that there are situations, high-volume request/response among them, that are not suited to it. The publishing part works great, and having competing consumers on the back-end is great, but having a front-end request wait on a defined, single-consumer response, does not scale well at all, because the MessageSessions take way too long to create via AcceptMessageSession() or BeginAcceptMessageSession(), and because they are not suited to caching.

If someone has an alternative view, I would love to hear it.

Comment: Sounds like something ZeroMQ is good at. http://www.zeromq.org/

Comment: OK, it's a very old question, but I see that there is a method `RenewLock` on the sessions now, so maybe now they are cacheable.

Comment: Excellent updates done to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This scenario is a classic request/response and a good candidate to use sessions. These are another correlation mechanism. Make a simple request queue and response queue. Each web role thread creates a unique sessionid for a request and puts that value in the "ReplyToSessionID" property of the brokeredmessage. Also this thread calls a [AcceptMessageSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh293162.aspx) on the response queue with the sessionid value so it locks it. The brokered message is sent to the request queue and all worker roles compete for messages. When a worker role gets a request it processes it, creates a response message and sets the sessionid property on the response message = replytosessinid of request. this is then sent to the response queue and will only be delivered to the thread that has locked that session id. A detailed sample [using sessions is here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Brokered-Messaging-Request-2b4ff5d8). There are 2 additional samples here using [Queues](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Brokered-Messaging-Request-0ce8fcaf) and [Topics](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Brokered-Messaging-Request-6759a36e) to achieve the request response correlation.

Comment: Thank you!! This is excellent, and was the "Missing Link" that I needed. Would I no longer need the Correlation Filters in this case, then? It seems that I can simply use Sessions without regard for the CorrelationId now.

Comment: I implemented this, first in blocking form, with SubscriptionClient.AcceptMessageSession(). The performance of that is unacceptable, as it seems to exhaust IIS threads. So, I moved on to SubscriptionClient.BeginAcceptMessageSession(). The problem now is that, in my callback method, the IAsyncResult parameter passed in is my SubscriptionClient, so that I can call EndAcceptMessageSession(). The bigger challenge is that, unlike AcceptMessageSession(), which returns a MessageSession, the MessageSession is not available. It is not in AsyncManager.Parameters, whose count is 0, nor anywhere else.

Comment: Async Call:    subClient.BeginAcceptMessageSession(sessionId, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), (ar) => { ProcessAcceptMessageSession(ar); }, subClient);    NOTE: Inside ProcessAcceptMessageSession(ar), I cannot find the session anywhere in scope, and the documentation is sparse.

Comment: Thanks for the good advice. Please see our update. We have switched to MessageSession, and I have a suspicion that this is another expensive object that needs to be cached and reused. Can you advise? Thank you. –

Comment: Why use request/response with a Queue instead of a Topic?

Comment: The *using sessions is here* link is dead

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach is to perform message correlation on the web role instance by using a dictionary of correlation ids and callback delegates.

Each web role (publisher) instance has a single subscription, filtered by a single subscription id, to the response topic.

Before a message is sent, the callback for that message is registered in the dictionary with the correlation id as the key. The correlation id and a subscription id is sent along with the message such that the response can be sent back to the correct subscription along with the correlation id.

Each web role instance monitors the single subscription and on receiving the response removes the dictionary entry and invokes the callback.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide insight into how would work in an AsyncController in MVC3? I could not use SubscriptionClient.Receive(), because it will block the IIS thread, so I use SubscriptionClient.BeginReceive() instead. I supply a callback function to BeginReceive(), and that is invoked when the async receive gets a message or times out. I am not understanding how, when I receive the message back from EndReceive(), why I would execute another callback, and how that would be affiliated to the original request in IIS, since IIS just grabs any old thread to service with, unless I call Sync().

Comment: So, what would the purpose of the callback in the Dictionary be? That's the connection I am unable to make at this time in my mind.

Comment: The subscription client would be receiving messages on its own thread and after looking up the correlation id in the dictionary, invoke the callback to the waiting IIS thread. Thus freeing up the waiting IIS thread and providing it with the response.

Comment: Ah, OK, so we could spin that up during app start via TPL or some such?

Comment: Correct, the single thread interacting with the subscription client can be fired up on startup. Essentially, my proposal splits correlating responses across two tiers. One at inter web role instance level using the subscription id (topic subscription) and another within a web role by using the correlation id.

Comment: This is a slick solution, as it solves the correlation challenge. I think it will lead to thread exhaustion under load, though, because the IIS thread cannot be freed from the request with this tactic. That was the original driver for us going with AsyncController. We tried spawing Tasks on CLR threads, but didn't gain much there either. So, AsyncController was the last resort, and we got the concurrent load way up, in terms of outstanding requests waiting on I/O, but we are getting killed on the wait time on initiating MessageSession on the SubscriptionClient. So many tradeoffs.

Comment: I have no experience with AsyncController but after a quick glance it seems to me that my proposal could fit in with that paradigm too; avoiding the thread exhaustion possibility under load, you rightly point out.

Answer (score 0):

For a single sender and receiver you need only have a single topic/subscription. You can set several [correlation filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.correlationfilter.aspx) on the same subscription and thus have all the responses that you need correlated show up at the same subscription. Currently we support up to [100,000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee732538.aspx) correlation filter instances on a single subscription and these can be added/removed (w/ transactions if needed) along with message send/receive operations on the topic/subscription.

In addition you can use Rules with Actions to stamp the message with additional properties if needed depending on which filter matched.

Comment: What about a situation with 12 instances in the Web Role (Publisher) and 6 instances in a Worker Role (Subscriber). We need each web request to be easily affiliated with its correlated response. What happens when a web instance places a message onto the Service Bus, tagged with a CorrelationId, which the Subscriber uses to tag the response message. How can one individual thread from the web front-end receive the correlated response? If the Topic is routing all matches to the Subscription, wouldn't a call to BeginReceive() just receive any of the correlated messages, rather than a specific one?